# libgdx actor won't change position

Tags: java, libgdx, actor, scene2d

If an actor is moved by its own `actor.act()` method, it updates the position flawlessly. But if I move the actor by a `group`, which contains the actor, with the `moveBy()` method or a `moveBy` action, the actor moves, but its getX() and getY() values stay the same as before the movement. Is there a way for the actor to update its position, when he is not being moved by its `act()` method, but rather from a outside method?

The snippet looks like this:

```
//Bounds are set in the MyActor class, which extends Actor
MyActor myActor= new MyActor();
Group group = new Group();
group.addActor(myActor)

//stage already created
stage.addActor(group);

//Doesn't update X and Y, when calling myActor.getX(), myActor.getY()
group.moveBy(x,y);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getX()` and `getY()` return position of actor in local coordinate. You can transform this position into stage's coordinate.

Actor having method `localToStageCoordinates(Vector2 localCoords)` that transforms the specified point in the actor's coordinates to be in the stage's coordinates

Create a class level Variable for local position.

```
Vector2 localPos= new Vector2();
```

set value in that localPos and

```
localPos.set(myActor.getX(),myActor.getY());
Vector2 stagedPos=group.localToStageCoordinates(localPos);
```

`stagedPos.x` and `stagedPos.y` is your requirement.

Test

```
public class TestGame extends Game implements InputProcessor{

    Stage stage;
    Image image;
    Group group;
    Vector2 vector2=new Vector2();

    @Override
    public void create() {

        stage=new Stage();
        group=new Group();

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);

        image=new Image(new Texture("image/base.png"));
        image.setPosition(100,100);

        group.addActor(image);
        stage.addActor(group);

        System.out.println("Initial Position of Actor : "+image.getX()+" And "+image.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        super.render();

        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
        gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.draw();
        stage.act();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);
        stage.getViewport().update(width,height);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        System.out.println("Actor Position Before moveBy on Group is : "+image.getX()+" And "+image.getY());

        group.moveBy(50,50);

        System.out.println("After moveBy applied on Group, Actor Position is : "+image.getX()+"And"+image.getY());
        vector2.set(image.getX(),image.getY());
        Vector2 stageCord=group.localToStageCoordinates(vector2);
        System.out.println("Position with Stage Cord. is : "+stageCord.x+" And "+stageCord.y);

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Output is :

Initial Position of Actor : 100.0 And 100.0 
Actor Position Before moveBy on Group is : 100.0 And 100.0 
After moveBy applied on Group, Actor Position is : 100.0 And 100.0 
 
Position with Stage Cord. is : 150.0 And 150.0

Comment: Im pretty sure that `group.localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(actor.getX(),actor.getY()));` wont return the correct value, but  `actor.localToStageCoordinates(new Vector2(0,0));` will, I might be wrong though but I have battle with this a few times, just in case this doesnt help you try my example

Comment: @centenond i tested and it's work fine as i explained, please check updated answer

Comment: look at that, guess I was doing it wrong all the time

Comment: @centenond Calling `localToStageCoordinates` on the group with the actor's coords is the same thing as calling on the actor with (0,0). Have a look at the source code. Vector (0,0) will be converted into the actor's coords in the group coordinate system and propagated upward.